# Magento 2 - Full width for a section in product view page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, layout, css

I add a new block in Product View page:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
     <container name="containertwo" as="containertwo" label="ontainer"  htmlTag="container" htmlClass="my-container" after="-">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="why-choose" after="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">why-choose</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Is there any way to made this full width, I mean to be on the entire window not in the page-wrapper?

I try this is CSS but is not work:

```
.my-container {
    width: 100%; 
    max-width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #666;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the problem like this

```
.my-container {
 width: 100vw;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: -50vw;
 left: 50%;
 padding: 50px 0;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding the important keyword?

```
.my-container {
    width: 100% !important; 
    max-width: 100% !important;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #666;
}
```

Comment: yes is the same, thank you

Comment: It could be because of the container that it is in. The upper layer is probably limiting the width. You can check that and see if that is editable.

Comment: is a default Luma theme and we talk about Product Page, so you can check this too

Comment: did you try 
`width: 100vw;`